# docker nginx, exit code 139

Tags: docker, nginx, hypriot

I'm trying to run a nginx webserver in docker, but it immediately stops with exit code 139.
This is a fresh setup, and the container doesn't generate a log.

Error 139:  Indicates failure as container received SIGSEGV.
So no idea what it can be:

setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3b+ & 16GB microSD
- running: [hypriotos-rpi-v1.12.3.img.zip](https://blog.hypriot.com/downloads/)
- Docker 19.03.12

I try to run nginx with:

```
docker run nginx
```

This stops with exit code 139 after a few seconds.
It uses the nginx:latest image (from 'pull nginx'). No other containers are running.
Other containers that don't give any problem: portainer, netdata, busybox.
also tried the 'rpi-nginx' image, but same error 139.

The result of 'docker inspect nginx':

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:7c554206e557aea70d592e48b168d66c8e5ee6604e064cbc20b92bff10a3bc3a",
        "RepoTags": [
            "nginx:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "nginx@sha256:c3a1592d2b6d275bef4087573355827b200b00ffc2d9849890a4f3aa2128c4ae"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2020-11-17T22:54:26.514640916Z",
        "Container": "758473294fb95509727018334cc52a102816a0c1c57e6e85a4dcf1158a5be180",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "758473294fb9",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"nginx\" \"-g\" \"daemon off;\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:3f83e43f035de87c25066e7044216d38353611558187fa4a3335b2c18d3e06a8",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:3f83e43f035de87c25066e7044216d38353611558187fa4a3335b2c18d3e06a8",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "Architecture": "arm",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 102509632,
        "VirtualSize": 102509632,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b7377edf293c2cca280779320a3eb4f9210f9149ca768798a43afa3b5d1aacef/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0751d900e8d7ab471e0876112be7a098be618e179702c5c547ea2f66ebcc4717/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3e60839ffc1ebd5cc4ecf21eae2bf2467fe504b953df4a8fa9f87bcfc23c72d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ef6e643beefb584790dda69a79126eb46236d651caed98e415abb1304b0ed5ec/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c4b8c7ab51f07f20e6ab25b3ad9f125f7d64c7dc56d84cddc650345e2b3d40f/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c4b8c7ab51f07f20e6ab25b3ad9f125f7d64c7dc56d84cddc650345e2b3d40f/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c4b8c7ab51f07f20e6ab25b3ad9f125f7d64c7dc56d84cddc650345e2b3d40f/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:70d894963bcc7f1b789cc5a26b02403a8144d4588bbc87739641155f5189b2ef",
                "sha256:310c1dc973cc0500d3367cc708b7268a2c44919acff89df8b17ac8898a7f9615",
                "sha256:7f24751cfac568fdbd1c646bfcc405fd952f7a4bfa3d55abb46782f6c65ff5f3",
                "sha256:d044176104cf5ee41702563ed781f9f38d71f78df9e25f6cf862a427d55f6970",
                "sha256:052ab1c348864a58088c6d1ccff5a8a5e32e5d5fed997bab49e7437f97fcf5d6"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Useful (kinda) indication from this [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/bmdg3v/nginx_exited_with_code_139_error/emwlodk/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): *Exit code > 128 means that process was terminated with a signal. In your case it's 11, because 128 + 11 = 139. Signal number 11 is segmentation fault.*

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks, I knew that (SIGSEGV) But aren't able to debug it :(

Answer (score 0):

The `nginx` image is build for amd64 architecture.
There is a variant targeting the arm64 architecture: `arm64v8/nginx`.

Comment: Thanks! But my 'docker inspect nginx' output shows: 
"Architecture": "arm",. So it should be arm? 

And aren't all 'docker official images' supposed to be multi architecture? And a pull from my raspberry pi is supposed to pull for that architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I am running my personal blog on a rpi at home with nginx. I even wrote an entire blog post on how to quickly set it up. You can clone it and have it up and running in minutes. I use balena.io to orchestrate it, it's super easy.

Here is the post: https://odyslam.me/blog/balena-nginx-rpi/

If you have any more questions, just shoot them up :)

P.S I am also using netdata in this setup. It's nuts (and for disclaimer, I work at Netdata).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not interested in the prepacked balena.io image, I want to install nginx on my rpi setup, and that doesn't seem to work. 
yeah Netdata is pretty powerfull.

Comment: @washichi you could use nginx in docker by using the same Docker image that I am using in balena. As far as I know, docker is supported on rpi.

Comment: Yeah true, but that image is packed inside the balena-first-app.img.zip. I could dive into that and see where it pulls the image from. But I'm 99% sure that's the same source I pull it from (the docker official nginx image). And yes docker & nginx is supported on the rpi. That's why it's weird I can't run an unmodified nginx. Maybe an hypriot issue?

Comment: Update: I checked, it's based on tobi312/rpi-nginx . I tried that image and also gave me 139 error. (nginx has now official arm images so tobi312 images are obsolete).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error , but solve it when I change the version of nginx to V1.18.0 now.

Comment: Thanks. do you have more information about your setup? or was it exactly the same? Downgrading might solve it for now, but I want to determine the root cause.